# Linq Group get percentage of overall

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I've come across a problem with my Linq query. Basically I have the below, taken from LinqPad, which groups by a date and a text field (type), and gives me the result. The problem is that I need to, for each date, have the total values, and a percentage of "blue" when compared to the total value.

```
var t = (from p in Orders where (p.Type == "Blue" || p.Metric == "Red" || p.Metric == "White")
&& p.OrderDate>= new DateTime(2014,8,26,0,0,0)
orderby p.OrderDate, p.Type
group p by new { p.OrderDate, p.Type} into gd 
select new {OrderDate = gd.Key.OrderDate, Type= gd.Key.Type, Value = gd.Sum(x => x.Value)}).ToList().Dump();
```

So if I have 3 rows like the ones below, I need to get one row back:

1. 2014-08-28, "Blue", 30
2. 2014-08-28, "Red", 25
3. 2014-08-28, "White", 95

The result I am after is:

1. 2014-08-28, "Blue", 0.2

The "0.2" is the percentage of "Blue" entries for a single date. Naturally if there are multiple dates I need 1 row per date :-)

This is doing my head in, so any pointers would be appreciated. As usual I did search on Google and here first, but after a few attempts have decided to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to do a `Join` to get what you want, as we are technically dealing with two sets of data, a dataset grouped by just the `OrderDate`, and a dataset grouped by `OrderDate`, and `Type`.

Please note, this is not tidy at all... So use with caution, I would also expect a detailed comment on code like this, because it's entirely unreadable.

```
var orderPercent = orders
    .GroupBy(x => x.OrderDate)
    .Join(
        orders.GroupBy(y => new { y.OrderDate, y.Type }),
        x => x.Key,
        y => y.Key.OrderDate,
        (a, b) => new { Date = a.Key, Type = b.Key.Type, Percent = (double)b.Sum(x => x.Value) / (double)a.Sum(x => x.Value) }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right of course, hard to maintain without comments.

Comment: @Dominik Yeah it's one of those weird situations where the LINQ is ugly, but still _probably?_ tidier than using loops.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to do this all in one query is quite difficult! I would advise you create two different sets, one for the set you have, then another grouped by date regardless of color.

next I would join the two sets by date.

I will work on an example if necessary.